# Combinatorics question related to round robin tournament, to prove that at least two teams have the same score

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> **Q.** In a football tournament of one round (each team plays each other once, 2 points for a win, 1 point to each team for draw, 0 for
> loss), 28 teams compete. During the tournament more than 75% of the
> matches end in a draw. Prove that there were two teams who ended up
> with the same final score

I have tried this question for a long time, but I haven't been able to come up with an approach that will prove the given result. Could anyone please provide a solution for this question. I have provided some useful information below

Total number of matches is 378. At least 284 matches have ended in a draw and at most 94 matches have ended with a victor.

Answer (score 2):

Each team has to have a different number of "wins-losses". For $k$ "wins-losses" a team would have to have played in at least $k$ decisive games.

Either $14$ or more teams have a positive "wins-losses" or $14$ or more teams have a negative "wins-losses". Without loss of generality suppose the former. Then the number of wins for these teams is at least $1+2+3+...+14=105$ which is greater than $94$.

Comment: +1 IMO the first line could be elaborated on.